# Excel not showing correct decimals

Tags: excel

I have a sql query on a data website to get sales data with correct decimals, e.g., 59.95.  But after getting the data into Excel automatically (get data from web), the amount becomes "60" and changing the number format to "number with 2 decimal places" still shows the incorrect "60.00" whereas it should have been 59.95.  I've searched online and couldn't find the solution. Any idea how to fix this?  Thanks.

Environment:
    Windows 10, 
    Excel from MS Office 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Change the data type to decimal number in the power query editor.